# SSRS - Referencing a Report Variable in an Expression

Tags: reporting-services

Is there a way to have a report header reference a report variable (called SubmissionNumber) that a user chooses from a dropdown box like: = "SERVICECENTERID_BCM001-M_" + **(Variables!SubmissionNumber.value)** + "*Inst_Mental_Disease_Rpt_v01*" + Format((Today), "yyyyMMdd")    - the bold part is giving an error so to speak

Answer (score 1):

This works: (Parameters!SubmissionNumber.value)